# Animated drag and drop in JTable

Tags: java, swing, animation, jtable, drag-and-drop

Do you know some way to make drag and drop in table more user-friendly? For example: row stick to mouse on drag, and other rows swap places when dragging. Can you recommend me some library for this ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you take a little time to have a read through [The Rabbit Hole](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/search?updated-min=2012-01-01T00:00:00-05:00&updated-max=2013-01-01T00:00:00-05:00&max-results=1) which has some excellent articles on the topic of drag'n'drop.

These are most of the articles of interest

- [Smooth JList Drop Target Animation](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/04/smooth-jlist-drop-target-animation.html)
- [Smooth Tree Drop Animation](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/smooth-tree-drop-animation.html)
- [My Drag Image is Better than Yours](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/my-drag-image-is-better-than-yours.html)
- [Dead Simple Drags](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/06/dead-simple-drags.html)
- [Fancy Drops](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/06/fancy-drops.html)
- [Drag Images for Everyone](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/06/fancy-drops.html)
- [Drop Target Navigation, or you drag your bags, let the doorman get the door](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/08/drop-target-navigation-or-you-drag.html)
- [Swing Drag Images (Improved)](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/08/swing-drag-images-improved.html)

Comment: Actually i implemented "Smooth JList" from The Rabbit Hole, but Mouse listener inside of JList child don´t work :(

Answer (score -2):

Well, Java libraries are usually not good really at the "animation" thing. There is a way to do this using the D and D libraries Java comes with but it would require swapping the values of the rows, rather than swapping the rows themselves.

Java is very limited at this kind of stuff. Either you hard code your own library, or use some other language that has libraries for tasks like these.